# TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function in jQuery 1.7.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, client-side, jquery-1.7

I am seeing a number of these errors in my JavaScript error logs:

> Object expected
>
> TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is
>   not a function

Unfortunately, I cannot replicate the error on any of these browsers when I try it myself. The line that I have highlighted is the one that is causing the error.

I have a read a bit about "No Conflict" mode and that may be a problem here, but I can't see what the issue would be by looking at the code that is below.

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 and it is served up from my server, rather than a CDN:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

My code:

```
$(function() {

    $('.imgCell').live("mouseenter", function() {
        if($(this).find('a img').length > 1) { // this line throws the error
            $(this).find('a img:eq(0)').hide();
        }   
    });

});
```

It does not appear to be affecting one specific browser either, as the following are affected: Chrome 26, Chromium 25, Firefox 10, Firefox 14, Firefox 16, Firefox 20, IE 10, IE 8, IE 9, Mobile Safari 6

Comment: How do you reference the Jquery files? Is it via a CDN or do you copy it locally?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Comment: @Liam I have a minified version of jQuery 1.7.2 locally. I have updated my question.

Comment: Of course your jquery code is wrapped inside a <script> tag not like in your example, right?

Comment: @Ravi Would this cause the error? And why can I not see it when I use these browsers?

Comment: @roasted Yes, I have updated my question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",'.imgCell', function() {
        //do something
    });
```

if you're using CDN, then you need to write fallback for it

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') { // load your JS file if CDN failed 
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/js/jquery-1.9.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));   
}
</script>
```

Comment: No, you are not using delegation here! Should be for complete equivalent to live: $(document).on('mouseenter','.imgCell',function(){...});  BTW, this has nothing to do with OP's question

Comment: document is not a tag element but an object: $(document) not $('document')

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `live` is deprecated, however is this why the error is occurring? Also, would it not error on the `live` line, rather than the line following it?

Comment: @Ravi Looks like there's a syntax error in your code on the first line (missing comma).

Comment: @Ravi I'll certainly give this a try, but as I don't seem to see the problem myself and can't confirm it's resolved i shall wait until this clears up in my JS error logs to mark as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use 'jQuery' instead of $ sign for example

```
jQuery(this).find('a img').length > 1
```

Comment: Why would the line that errors cause the error, but the reference to `$` in the line not error?

Comment: I am not getting you, can you please explain your comment ?

I had the same issue some time before and applied the mentioned solution which resolved the error. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Well, from your answer it would suggest that the reference to `$` is a problem. But there is a reference to `$` in the line above, but it does not error. Why would that be? BTW, I did not downvote you.